# Defining placeholders for source and schema name in a query inside SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, sqldatasource

I am using a following query with hardcoded datasource name in my OLE DB source of SSIS package wherefrom I am pulling certain types of rows.

```
select * 
from mtb.dbo.TRS_Trans_For_EY_Incl_Wire_Info_20131004 AS src 
where 'TRS-' + src.Transaction_Type_Cd 
NOT IN ( 
select dtp.trans_type_cd 
from mtb_etl.dbo.tb_transaction_type AS dtp
where dtp.cust_indicator = 'I')
```

My question is how can I use a standard query (instead of a hardcoded one) to pull the data so it can work well for various datasources?

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!!! I found it!

```
select * 
from [dbo].[TRS_Trans_For_EY_Incl_Wire_Info_20131004]  
where 'TRS-' + [Transaction_Type_Cd] 
NOT IN ( 
select [trans_type_cd] 
from [dbo].[tb_transaction_type] 
where [cust_indicator] = 'I')
```